# Karate - How to obtain response using execution hook

Tags: karate

I have the following feature file:

```
    Given def query = karate.call('classpath:query/Story/FindStoryByID.js')
    And def variables = { id: "xxyy" }
    And request { query: '#(query)', variables: '#(variables)' }
    When method POST
    Then status 200
    And match response.data.FindStoryByID.id != '#null'
```

I am currently trying to do a `beforeStep` in order to write whole GraphQL request (`query`) of the feature to a file using `karate.write`.

So far I have come up with this:

```
    @Override
    public boolean beforeStep(Step step, ScenarioContext context) {
    if (step.getText().trim().contains("request {")) {
        System.out.println(step.getText());
    }
    return true;
}
```

This successfully triggers a print, which indicates I am poking on the right direction. The problem is that I haven't still able to figure out what should I do to access a variable (`query`) like the one we can do on a JS/Feature file (`karate.get('query');`)

I am wondering if it is even possible to achieve such feat through the execution hook like this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Ah found it! This do the job

```
context.vars.get("query"));
```

Comment: yes, you can also do more complex JS expressions via `ctx.eval(string)`